# Want macro to get the sheetname of a workbook located in defferent location

Tags: excel, vba

Below is the code which i used, which will get the sheetname on the current workbook, but i want to specify where the workbook is located and the workbook name.And then get the sheet names of that particular workbook

```
Sub GetSheetName()
    Const SHTNAME As String = "Index to Sheets"
    Dim indexSheet As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    On Error Resume Next
        Worksheets(SHTNAME).Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
        With Worksheets.Add(before:=Worksheets(1))
            .Name = SHTNAME
            For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
                .Cells(i, 1).Value = Worksheets(i).Name
            Next i
        End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that the "other" workbook is not currently open:

```
Sub GetNames()
    Dim s1 As String, s2 As String, s3 As String
    Dim s4 As String, ws As Worksheet
    s1 = "C:\TestFolder\"
    s2 = "ABC.xlsx"
    s3 = s1 & s2
    Workbooks.Open s3
    For Each ws In Sheets
        s4 = s4 & vbCrLf & ws.Name
    Next ws
    ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    MsgBox s4
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Gary's Student, Can you please explain the code. since im not sure why we need to declare 2 workbook name. s1 = "C:\TestFolder\"
s2 = "ABC.xlsx" . Also my requirement was that just when we run a macro, it should get sheetnames of the workbook we have speficfied. Note: The file will be placed in some different location.